# Using imagemagick instead of mathjax when exporting HTML in org-mode

Tags: emacs, imagemagick, latex, org-mode

I want to use imagemagick to create image files instead of MathJax when exporting to HTML.

How would I go about doing this?

I came across [LaTeX Fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html) from the manual, and it mentions `org-format-latex-header` variable, but I am unsure what to set this to in order to use imagemagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html#Math-formatting-in-HTML-export) states you should be able to use the following option at the start of your buffer:

```
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
```

If this doesn't work you may also want to try the `latex` (not `tex`) key. i.e.:

```
#+OPTIONS: latex:imagemagick
```

Comment: As an added note, you can modify `org-format-latex-options` to control how the image gets exported.